# BLE SMP packets sniffing using scapy python

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, scapy

[image: SMP packet i want to sniff]
I want to sniff SMP packets from a bluetooth socket using the python scapy library or using another tool. I expect to use such a function on Windows, but I don’t know if this is possible even on Linux. Please tell me what I can do to achieve my goal

I was able to sniff such packets using the usual wireshark launch on Linux and on Windows using btvs.exe. I also saw that using scapy on Linux you can sniff HCI packets

So, to collect SMP pascket using wireshark on linux i just opended wireshark and started sniffing, connected to BLE device.
To collect HCI packets using scapy i did next:
[scapy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cal6m.png)
Then i just copy it to pcap using "`wrpcap("/tmp/bluetooth.pcap", pkts)`"
On windows i collected SMP by "`.\btvs.exe -Mode Wireshark`" in powershell

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: code of what do you mean?

Comment: If I understood correctly, I added it